# reading into variables from "piped" data

Tags: bash, sort, read

I have a csv (Fieldseparator is the ',') file with data in it and I would have to prepare the csv before reading it (mainly just sort it) into variables. How can I read the sorted stream into variables? I tried something like this:

```
while IFS="," read -r dat kto_soll kto_haben betrag kostenobj
do
  printf "date: %s" "${dat}"
done < $(tail -n +2 /tmp/myFile | sort -t "," -k1 -r)
done
```

but I get an error: "Mehrdeutige Umlenkung" which translates to "ambiguous redirection"

What did I do wrong or better: how am I supposed to solve this?

Comment: You just need `done < <(` instead of `done < $(`, and remove the extra `done` in the last line

Comment: Thanks for the hint @muru Works like a charm now. Could you please expand on why < <( is working, whereas the <$( which I would normally use to pipe outputs of commands to something does not?

Comment: Briefly, `$(...)` runs the command and uses the output as if it was on the command line.  `<(...)` runs the command and returns a file path to the output.  Compare `cat $(echo hello)` which might return `cat: hello: No such file or directory` to `cat <(echo hello)` which will output `hello`.  We can see this with `echo $(echo hello)` (returns `hello`) and `echo <(echo hello)` (returns something like `/dev/fd/4`).  In your case you want `< <(...)` because you want the output of `tail` to be read as file input to the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!